# Failed to join domain: failed to set machine kerberos encryption types: Insufficient access

Tags: centos, active-directory, kerberos, domain

Has anyone gotten this error when trying to join CentOS 7 to Active Directory? I tried various ways(via cli, gui, tui) and always get same error.

```
Failed to join domain: failed to set machine kerberos encryption types: Insufficient access
```

Comment: do you use an AD account with admin right ?

Comment: Yes, I tried to join RHEL 6.4 with same method to AD and it succeeded.

Comment: post here the command what you did in the cli, please

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Windows_Integration_Guide/winbind-auth.html
Do by this guide, and every tuturial is very similar to this.
Also tried with **realm join** command with adjusting all required parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The solutions were just in front of me. Although error appears the machine is joined to AD, the error is misleading.
Useful command for checking if a machine is in AD: `net ads -P status`.

To provide machine stay in AD you need to create a kerberos ticket with the `kinit` command.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully  run:

```
net ads testjoin
```

Even after receiving the same message on CentOS 7.  I can login via my company AD successfully.

Comment: I get output when I run `net ads testjoin`:  Join is OK